# npm production build issue (npm version build -Pprod)

Tags: node.js, npm, jhipster

**Versions**

```
c:\dev\sam>npm -v
5.5.1

c:\dev\sam>node -v
v8.9.2

c:\dev\sam>
```

**Issue**

```
c:\dev\sam> mvnw -Pprod -DskipTests package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SAM 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ sam ---
[INFO] Node v6.11.0 is already installed.
[INFO] NPM 5.0.3 is already installed.
...
INFO] ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss
[INFO] Module build failed: Error: Missing binding c:\dev\sam\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node
[INFO] Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x
[INFO]
[INFO] Found bindings for the following environments:
[INFO]   - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 8.x
[INFO]
[INFO] This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
[INFO] Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
...
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 20.684 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-12T06:56:14+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 35M/501M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**package.json**

```
c:\dev\sam>more package.json
{
  "name": "sam",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Description for SAM",
  "private": true,
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.25.1",
    "angular-highcharts": "6.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "highcharts": "6.1.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.5",
    "ng-jhipster": "0.4.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "1.7.7",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "4.1.2",
    "ngx-cookie": "2.0.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "0.5.1",
    "ngx-stripe": "0.8.2",
    "ngx-webstorage": "2.0.1",
    "nouislider": "11.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "sockjs-client": "1.1.4",
    "swagger-ui": "2.2.10",
    "tether": "1.4.0",
    "webstomp-client": "1.0.6",
    "zone.js": "0.8.19",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.8.5",
    "@types/highcharts": "5.0.22",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.107",
    "@types/node": "8.0.18",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.2",
    "browser-sync": "2.18.13",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "1.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "4.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.2.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "generator-jhipster": "4.14.3",
    "html-loader": "0.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.7.0",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-intl-shim": "1.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
    "karma-notify-reporter": "1.0.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.6.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.16",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.9",
    "proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "source-map": "0.6.1",
    "sourcemap-istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "tslint": "5.5.0",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
    "typescript": "2.6.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.1.5",
    "web-app-manifest-loader": "0.1.1",
    "webpack": "3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.5",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.1",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.5.1",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "4.1.0",
    "xml2js": "0.4.17"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "source-map": "0.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json -e 'node_modules/**'",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "ngc": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
    "cleanup": "rimraf target/{aot,www}",
    "clean-www": "rimraf target//www/app/{src,target/}",
    "start": "npm run webpack:dev",
    "serve": "npm run start",
    "build": "npm run webpack:prod",
    "test": "npm run lint && karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch",
    "webpack:dev": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --inline --hot --profile --port=9060 --watch-content-base",
    "webpack:build:main": "npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "webpack:build": "npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:build:main",
    "webpack:prod:main": "npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile",
    "webpack:prod": "npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:prod:main && npm run clean-www",
    "webpack:test": "npm run test",
    "webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
    "postinstall": "node node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js"
  }
}
```

**Question**

I'm not sure why this is failing.

The dev build is working perfectly.

The prod build fails (it never worked).

For some reason npm is looking for a different version of nodejs (6) rather than the version I have installed (8), perhaps ?

I do have a binding file but not the one that the build is looking for.

I have cleaned down my node_modules and installed again but that hasn't solved the issue.

I have tried the npm rebuild node-sass but perhaps this is downloading the version that is there (8) rather than (6) ?

Should I "downgrade" to 6 ?
Or how do I upgrade the build ?

Any advise on how to resolve this and what the reason for the above is ?

And what the correct configuration should be ?

Note: this is a jhipster generated project (if that makes any difference).

Thanks a million for taking the time to explain this.

Kind regards,
Fergal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prod build does not use the version of node you installed on your PC, it installs one locally under node sub folder as specified in the pom.xml. So you could try to edit your pom.xml and use same version of node and npm as your PC.

Comment: I changed the pom.xml to use the same version and then rebuilt. 
The newer versions were downloaded and the issue was resolved.
Thanks for that.

(Note: I have another issue now but I'll post separately on that).